# How do I write a generic Java enum rotator?

Tags: java, enumeration

How do I make a generic enum rotator?  It would be a generic version of `next()` in this example.

```
    public class TestEnum
    {
        enum Temperature { hot, cold };

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Temperature t = Temperature.hot;
            Temperature t2 = next(t);
        }

        static Temperature next(Temperature t)
        {
            if (t.ordinal() == Temperature.values().length - 1)
                return Temperature.values()[0];
            else
                return Temperature.values()[t.ordinal() + 1];
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** In the comments, `@irreputable` suggests a superior solution.  `irreputable` if you post it as an answer I will select it.  You might want to save time by copying this answer.

```
static <T extends Enum<T>> T next(T t)
{
    int index = t.ordinal();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Enum<T>[] constants = t.getClass().getEnumConstants();
    if (index == constants.length - 1)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T result = (T)constants[0];
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T result = (T)constants[index + 1];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
public class Test {

    enum Temperature { hot, cold };

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            Temperature t = Temperature.hot;
            Temperature t2 = next(t);
            System.out.println(t2);
        }

        static <T extends Enum> T next(T t) throws Exception
        {
            Method values = t.getClass().getMethod("values");
            if (t.ordinal() == ((T[])values.invoke(t)).length - 1)
                return ((T[])values.invoke(t))[0];
            else
                return ((T[])values.invoke(t))[t.ordinal() + 1];
        }
}
```

Comment: As a general purpose rotator, I think this is a good answer. I am going to use this, plus `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, `<T extends Enum<?>>` to define the type, and explicitly catch `NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException` and I will throw `RuntimeException` because I think enum rotation is low risk.

Comment: use `Class.getEnumConstants()`

Answer (score 5):

IMO, relying on position to think of "next" or "previous" would be a bad idea, just as it is a bad idea to rely on ordinal() in your application code. It would make more sense to have your enum determine *how* the rotation should take place so that adding new members in between wouldn't screw up stuff.

There are two solutions you can try out: making sure each enum created implicitly handles the next intelligently which provides for greater degree of flexibility or create a generic rotation policy which can be used by all enums which supports rotation but has less flexibility.

Approach 1 (greater flexibility)

```
enum Direction1 {

    EAST() {
        @Override
        public Direction1 next(Rotation rotation) {
            return rotation == Rotation.CLOCKWISE ? SOUTH : NORTH;
        }
    },
    WEST() {
        @Override
        public Direction1 next(Rotation rotation) {
            return rotation == Rotation.CLOCKWISE ? NORTH : SOUTH;
        }
    },
    SOUTH() {
        @Override
        public Direction1 next(Rotation rotation) {
            return rotation == Rotation.CLOCKWISE ? WEST : EAST;
        }
    },
    NORTH() {
        @Override
        public Direction1 next(Rotation rotation) {
            return rotation == Rotation.CLOCKWISE ? EAST : WEST;
        }
    };

    abstract Direction1 next(Rotation rotation);

    static enum Rotation {
        CLOCKWISE, ANTICLOCKWISE
    };

}
```

Approach 2, more generic, less flexibility

```
interface Rotatable {
    // now it would be difficult to make next() method take a rotation
    Rotatable next();
}

enum Direction2 implements Rotatable {

    // assume clockwise rotation

    EAST() {
        @Override
        public Direction2 next() {
            return SOUTH;
        }
    },
    WEST() {
        @Override
        public Direction2 next() {
            return NORTH;
        }
    },
    SOUTH() {
        @Override
        public Direction2 next() {
            return WEST;
        }
    },
    NORTH() {
        @Override
        public Direction2 next() {
            return EAST;
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an interface:

```
public interface EnumInterface {
    public EnumInterface[] values1();
    public int ordinal1();
}   

enum Temperature implements EnumInterface {
    HOT,
    COLD;

    public EnumInterface[] values1() {
        return values();
    }

    public int ordinal1() {
        return ordinal();
    }
}

static <T extends EnumInterface> T next(T t) {      
    if (t.ordinal1() == t.values1().length - 1)
        return (T) t.values1()[0];
    else
        return (T) t.values1()[t.ordinal1() + 1];
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Temperature t = Temperature.HOT;
    Temperature t2 = next(t);
    System.out.println(t2);
}
```

Comment: This is okay for the .ordinal() but it does not compile at the .values().

Comment: @broiyan, well apparently the Enum class itself does not define such a method.

Comment: Yes but Temperature has .values().

Comment: how can a method be generic that uses a specific method of a single class?

Comment: @Tudor: without the ability to call `values()` this won't work. I have a feeling that the question is non-solvable due to Java's broken implementation of generics.

Comment: @JensSchauder: It can if the method is of a super class that the generics are bound to.

Comment: Indeed, as I've written in my edit, the values method is added by the compiler to any user-created enum, but it does not exist in the Enum class itself.

Comment: @broiyan: See if this version is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to a question but rather a different approach to what you are trying to do.

```
public interface<T extends Enum<T>> NextEnum {
    T next();
}

public enum Temperature implements NextEnum<Temperature> {
    hot, cold;

    public Temperature next() {
        if (ordinal() == Temperature.values().length - 1)
            return Temperature.values()[0];
        else
            return Temperature.values()[ordinal() + 1];
    }
}
```

For all enums that implement `NextEnum` you can use the `next()` method. For example:

```
Temperature.hot.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using ordinal values is always a fragile approach as it will rely on position, either use `values()` or `class.getEnumConstants()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T rotate(T current, int increment) {
  T[] values = current.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
  int i = current.ordinal() + increment;
  while (i<0) i+= values.length; 
  return values[i%values.length];
}

Temperature next = rotate(hot, 1);
Temperature prev = rotate(hot, -1);
Temperature nextNext = rotate(hot, 2);
```